# Docker Write to a specific path in the host machine?

Tags: docker

I have a docker container running beautifully , my problem is that , the container processes some data and stores the O/P in the container but I would like it to be mounted on the disk ( at a specific path ) . I have used the volume option but it may be such that I am using it in a wrong way or is there another way . Sorry if this question is repetitive . Can anyone explain about the bind mounts concept ?

Answer (score 0):

Bind mounts have limited functionality compared to volumes. When you use a bind mount, a file or directory on the host machine is mounted into a container. The file or directory is referenced by its full or relative path on the host machine. By contrast, when you use a volume, a new directory is created within Docker’s storage directory on the host machine, and Docker manages that directory’s contents.
If you use --mount to bind-mount a file or directory that does not yet exist on the Docker host, Docker does not automatically create it for you, but generates an error.

```
$ docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name devtest \
  --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/target,target=/app \
  nginx:latest
```

If you use -v or --volume to bind-mount a file or directory that does not yet exist on the Docker host, -v creates the endpoint for you. It is always created as a directory.

```
$ docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name devtest \
  -v "$(pwd)"/target:/app \
  nginx:latest
```

Refer: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/